# django about deleteview and view

Tags: python, django

I am creating a bulletin board that communicates by DB <> API <> WEB method.

I want to create a view to delete comments, but an Improperly Configured error occurs when I request to delete comments from the web. Can I define a query set without Model,DB? Or is my code a problem? Which view should I use?

**Improperly Configured Error with deleteview, Method not allowed with view**

generic.deleteview
[image]

view

[image]

WEB view.py

```
class Commentapi_delete(generic.DeleteView):
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    datas = {
        'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
        'id': self.kwargs['id']
    }

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/boardapi/' + str(datas['pk']) + '/comment/' + str(datas['id']) + '/delete/'
    c_delete = requests.delete(url, params=datas)

    print(datas)
    print(c_delete)

    return redirect(reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}))
```

API view.py

```
class CommentUpdateDeleteView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Comment
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

EDIT
WEB view.py

```
class Commentapi_delete(generic.DeleteView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data ={
        'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
        'id': self.kwargs['id']
    }

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/boardapi/' + str(data['pk']) + '/comment/'
    c_get = requests.get(url, params=data)

    return **What shoud i return?**

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    datas = {
        'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],
        'id': self.kwargs['id']
    }

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/boardapi/' + str(datas['pk']) + '/comment/' + str(datas['id']) + '/delete/'
    c_delete = requests.delete(url, params=datas)

    print(datas)
    print(c_delete)

    return redirect(reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}))
```

html

```
    <form action="{% url 'comment_delete' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 0;padding-right: 5px;" align="right" width="10%">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-right:10px;">Delete</button> 
            </td>
    </form>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div>
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="height:45px;border-top:solid 1px #dddddd;">
            <td width="20%" align="left" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px;"><input type="input" name="c_writer" placeholder="writer" /></td>
            <td width="80%" align="left" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px;"><textarea name="c_note" rows="4"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-right:10px;">save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Error
[image]

Comment: The `get` method of `DeleteView` is supposed to display a form to confirm the deletion of the object, when you make a GET request to it, it obviously tries to get the object needed, you should override it in that case.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat What should I do?

Comment: override the `get` method like you do for the `delete` method and get the data from the API to display in the page. Or you can also try overriding `get_object`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I modified it as much as I understood it. You can start with EDIT WEB view.py. What should I return from get method? And what should I put in html form action url?I don't know what to put in form action url because there is no model.

Comment: Remove the forms action attribute that would mean it's action is to the current url itself. From the return in the get method you just need to render this template (potentially passing the details of the object to be deleted in the context so you can show it to the user and confirm they really want to delete it)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat if delete the forms action. Comments are made when the delete button is pressed. I think the post below applies.

Answer (score 0):

The generic.DeleteView seems to be the correct one, but you haven't defined your queryset, you did so in your `CommentUpdateDeleteView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView)`, u should either define you queryset in a similar way on your `Commentapi_delete(generic.DeleteView)` or override the get_queryset method on the class to return you own desired queryset.

Comment: I don'k know what queryset to return